# Error: Delete then insert using JPA in single transaction

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

Using JPA and mysql,I want to write program for delete and insert into a table in single transaction using @Transaction annotation

My code is like this

```
 //Delete 
entityManager.createNamedQuery( "DELETE_QUERY" ).setParameter( "userId", userId ).executeUpdate();

entityManager.flush();


//Insert

User user = new User();
user.setUserId(122);
user.setPassword("test");

entityManager.merge( user );
entityManager.flush();
```

Delete query is displayed. Then the update query is running here...Then it throw the below mentioned error

..............

javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

...............

Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
...............
...............
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a field annotated with `@Version` in your User entity, which is precisely used for optimistic locking, making sure that when you update a user, you're passing the same version in the user object as the one stored in the database.

But you're not, because you're creating a user that already exists in database from scratch, with its version field having its default value. So you get this exception.

Comment: Thanks Nizet for quick reply. I need to delete one user record and insert another user record in same transaction. But while inserting, it shows update query. What I need to make change in the code?

Comment: It shows an update query because you're using merge(), and you're passing an entity with an ID, which is thus supposed to already exist in the database. If you want to insert an entity, then use persist(), and don't specify any ID: let Hibernate generate the ID. Providing the code of your entity and telling what the user table contains would help.